# Multiple editors in handsontable

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I'm wondering how its possible to use multiple editors in handsontable.js library.

I'm using the `columns` option to specify each column attributes.
Some of them show a list with the possible options for the cell:

```
{
    data: 3,
    type: 'autocomplete',
    source: function (query, process) {
        response = JSON.parse($('#options').val());
        process(response);
    },
    strict: false,
    allowInvalid: true,
},
```

In this case, it will generate the list of options in the `source` option.

Now, I would like to add another editor as per [this other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29654330/create-onedit-callback-in-handsontable) but I noticed that if I add it in the columns declaration then I lose the source option that generates the autocomplete list:

```
{
    //START
    data: 3,
    type: 'autocomplete',
    source: function (query, process) {
        response = JSON.parse($('#start_array').val());
        process(response);
    },
    strict: false,
    allowInvalid: true,
    editor: LoggingEditor //added here
}
```

Any solution to this?

[Reproduction of the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/fws1vc5e/21/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handsontable is using [cascading configuration](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/wiki/Options#how-does-cascading-configuration-work), which is way to provide configuration options for whole table, its columns or particular cells.

In your case specifying the `type` attribute (you mentioned it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29654330/create-onedit-callback-in-handsontable#comment47634747_29708345)) trumps the top-level `editor: LoggingEditor` property. To use a custom editor you have to either not specify a type (because the default is text) or add the `editor` property to all column definitions. I've  edited your example to utilize both methods in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7x8so90j/) (note that the autocomplete field do not work, but you should add another custom editor and not use the text one).

Comment: So, isn't there any way to use an editor and at the same time use `type: autocomplete` ?

Comment: I created a reproduction of the issue [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fws1vc5e/21/). As you can see, I'm using an `editor` and a `type` attribute for each column. And yet, the autocomplete doesn't work.

Comment: It [will work](http://jsfiddle.net/hb5ujwkn/) if you extend from `AutocompleteEditor` for the `type: 'autocomplete'` columns. Take a look at the [custom editors](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/wiki/Custom-cell-editor) page at the HOT wiki and [editor implementations](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/tree/master/src/editors).